# Creating Form Controls at run time using FormArray

Tags: angular, formarray

Wanted to practice `FormArray`
So I have this:

```
  myFrom: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myFrom = fb.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: [''],
      address: fb.group({
        street: ['', Validators.required],
        city: [''],
        zip: [''],
      }),
      aliases: fb.array(
        [fb.control('')]
      )
    });
  }

  get aliases() {
    return this.myFrom.get('aliases') as FormArray;
  }
```

So the `aliases` is the one that is at runtime using `FormArray`.
So I added a method that I can connect to a button:

```
  addAnotherAlias() {
    this.aliases.push(this.myFrom.control(''));
  }
```

But I am doing something wrong, because errors that `control` is not a property on `myForm` and I should use `controls` instead.

Answer (score 0):

OK found the problem. control is part of FormBuilder factory methods. so I should say:

```
  addAnotherAlias() {
    this.aliases.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }
```